# Activation of allocation/contribution

Tags: wallets

I cannot activate my recommended allocation after I entered my "public key hash" and "activation code."

I get the following feedback:

> We were unable to activate a recommended allocation corresponding to
>   the information that was entered. Please make sure that a public key
>   hash from the fundraiser and the associated activation code obtained
>   after completing the Foundation’s KYC/AML process here are entered
>   correctly. If a balance for a given public key hash from the
>   fundraiser appears on a Tezos block explorer, then the activation
>   process has already been completed and no further action is needed.

Please can someone advice on the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried following this guide: https://medium.com/@PosBakerz/how-to-recover-your-tezos-from-ico-4088899fc4a3

Make sure you are entering your public key and the correct activation code!

Comment: My activation code and public key are all correct, I just copied it from my Tezos KYC page.

Answer (score 1):

The most common activation issue is the password since most of the other information is copy/pasted from your fundraiser PDF.

Make sure you are actually copy/pasting from the PDF (Because if you had a typo in your email, and it's in the fundraiser PDF with a typo, your actual email address without the typo would not work. You would need to input the one with the typo).

You should always keep an eye out for random spaces after pasting something. It's easy to accidentally paste something with an added space before or behind the actual content.

I don't know what wallet you are using to recover your XTZ, but I recommend downloading Galleon: https://galleon-wallet.tech/
Then follow this simple youtube tutorial to import your fundraiser wallet: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eD-y1cEwB94

If you are still experiencing difficulties I recommend you contact the Tezos Foundation directly by sending an email to activation@tezos.com   &   support@tezos.com.